# would it be equivalent to find this remainder?

Tags: number-theory

I was given this exercise: Suppose that  $N$ is written in the decimal system in the form $N=a_m a_{m-1} \dots a_1 a_0 $.

Prove that $11 \mid N \Leftrightarrow 11|a_0-a_1+ \dots+(-1)^{m-1}a_{m-1}+(-1)^m a_{m}$.

So,if I would have to find the remainder of the division of $N$ by $11$,could I find the remainder of the division of $a_0-a_1+ \dots+(-1)^{m-1}a_{m-1}+(-1)^m a_{m}$ by $11$ ??

Answer (score 1):

The key of your problem is $11|(10^{k}-1)$ for all even $k$ and $11|(10^k+1)$ for all odd $k$. Since 
$$
N=a_m a_{m-1} \dots a_1 a_0=\sum_{i=0}^ma_i10^i,
$$
then
\begin{align}
11|N&\iff 11|\sum_{i=0}^ma_i10^i\\
&\iff 11|\left(\sum_{i\textrm{ odd}}^ma_i10^i+\sum_{i\textrm{ even}}^ma_i10^i\right)\\
&\iff 11|\left(\sum_{i\textrm{ odd}}^ma_i(10^i+1)+\sum_{i\textrm{ even}}^ma_i(10^i-1)-\sum_{i\textrm{ odd}}^ma_i+\sum_{i\textrm{ even}}^ma_i\right).\\
\end{align}
Now using the two facts above, you will lead to what you wanted.

Comment: I have proven that $11 \mid N \Leftrightarrow 11|a_0-a_1+ \dots+(-1)^{m-1}a_{m-1}+(-1)^m a_{m}$.
I was just wondering if the remainder of the division of $N$ by $11$ equal is to the remainder of the division of $a_0-a_1+ \dots +(-1)^{m-1}a_{m-1}+(-1)^m a_m$ by 11..

Comment: Yes, sure. If $N=11q+r$ and $a_0-a_1+ \dots+(-1)^{m-1}a_{m-1}+(-1)^m a_{m}=11s+t$ for some integers $q,r,s,t$ with $0\le r,t<11$ then $11 \mid N \Leftrightarrow 11|a_0-a_1+ \dots+(-1)^{m-1}a_{m-1}+(-1)^m a_{m}$ implies $11|(r-t)$ that gives you $r=t$.

Comment: Nice,thanks.....!!

Answer (score -1):

Mo you can not find it. If you have seen its proof this strategy works because because 9999...uptil even number of terms is removed as out will always be facor and in odd digits 10000...1 is divisible so we remove that factor
  sorry I mis understood your question I gave the explanation  for divisor . We can find the remainder it will be either number yor are getting let say n so it will be n or 11-n for n>0  and -n or n+11

Comment: I haven't understood the reason why we cannot do it like that.

Comment: sorry I mis understood your question I gave the explanation  for divisor .

Comment: sorry I mis understood your question I gave the explanation  for divisor . We can find the remainder it will be either number yor are getting let say n so it will be n or 11-n for n>0  and -n or n+11

Comment: If you want exactly what will be remainder .i must give you a hint to find it yourself .if you have some problem comment again. Try to find its proof or you can  pass through I its proof by observing patterns in taking few examples and see what are  the answers you get for even and odd terms